# Why were metamorphoses so popular with ancient writers?

Tags: greek, roman, concepts, motifs

A brief search revealed five books by Greek and Roman writers on the subject of metamorphosis myths:

- "Metamorphoses" by Ovid
- "Metamorphoseon Synagoge" by Antoninus Liberalis
- "Metamorphoses (aka The Golden Ass)" by Lucius Apuleius
- "Ornithogonia" by Boeus
- "Heteroioumena" by Nicander of Colophon

There probably are others. The metamorphosis theme was apparently very popular in ancient times.